# Sort values across multiple columns in R with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

Apologies for the not-particularly-clear title - hoping my example below helps. I am working with some sports data, attempting to compute "lineup statistics" for certain grouping of players in the data. Below is an example of the type of data I'm working with `(playerInfo)`, as well as the type of analysis I am attempting to do `(groupedInfo)`:

```
playerInfo = data.frame(
  lineup = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
  player1 = c("Bil", "Tom", "Tom", "Nik", "Nik", "Joe"),
  player1id = c("e91", "a27", "a27", "b17", "b17", "3b3"),
  player2 = c("Nik", "Bil", "Nik", "Joe", "Tom", "Tom"),
  player2id = c("b17", "e91", "b17", "3b3", "a27", "a27"),
  player3 = c("Joe", "Joe", "Joe", "Tom", "Joe", "Nik"),
  player3id = c("3b3", "3b3", "3b3", "a27", "3b3", "b17"),
  points = c(6, 8, 3, 12, 36, 2),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

groupedInfo <- playerInfo %>%
  dplyr::group_by(player1, player2, player3) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(
    lineup_ct = n(),
    total_pts = sum(points)
  )

> groupedInfo
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   player1, player2 [?]
  player1 player2 player3 lineup_ct total_pts
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>       <int>     <dbl>
1 Bil     Nik     Joe             1         6
2 Joe     Tom     Nik             1         2
3 Nik     Joe     Tom             1        12
4 Nik     Tom     Joe             1        36
5 Tom     Bil     Joe             1         8
6 Tom     Nik     Joe             1         3
```

The goal here is to group_by the 3 players in each row, and then compute some summary statistics (in this simple example, count and sum-of-points) for the different groups. Unfortunately, what `dplyr::group_by` is missing is the fact that certain groups of players should be the same group of players, if its the same 3 players simply in different columns.

For example, in the dataframe above, rows 3,4,5,6 all have the same 3 players (Nik, Tom, Joe), however because sometimes Nik is player1, and sometimes Nik is player2, etc., the group_by groups them separately.

For clarity, below is an example of the type of results I am seeking to get:

```
correctPlayerInfo = data.frame(
  lineup = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
  player1 = c("Bil", "Bil", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe"),
  player1id = c("e91", "e91", "3b3", "3b3", "3b3", "3b3"),
  player2 = c("Joe", "Joe", "Nik", "Nik", "Nik", "Nik"),
  player2id = c("3b3", "3b3", "b17", "b17", "b17", "b17"),
  player3 = c("Nik", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom"),
  player3id = c("b17", "a27", "a27", "a27", "a27", "a27"),
  points = c(6, 8, 3, 12, 36, 2),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

correctGroupedInfo <- correctPlayerInfo %>%
  dplyr::group_by(player1, player2, player3) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(
    lineup_ct = n(),
    total_pts = sum(points)
  )

> correctGroupedInfo
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   player1, player2 [?]
  player1 player2 player3 lineup_ct total_pts
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>       <int>     <dbl>
1 Bil     Joe     Nik             1         6
2 Bil     Joe     Tom             1         8
3 Joe     Nik     Tom             4        53
```

In this second example, I have manually sorted the data alphabetically such that player1 < player2 < player3. As a result, when I do the group_by, it accurately groups rows 3-6 into a single grouping.

How can I achieve this programatically? I'm not sure if (a) re-structuring playerInfo into the column-sorted correctPlayerInfo (as I've done above(), or (b) some other approach where group_by automatically identifies that these are the same groups, is best.

I am actively working on this, and will post updates if I can come about to my own solution. Until then, any help with this is greatly appreciated!

**Edit:** Thus far I've tried something along these lines:

```
newPlayerInfo <- playerInfo %>%
  dplyr::mutate(newPlayer1 = min(player1, player2, player3)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(newPlayer3 = max(player1, player2, player3))
```

... to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create group IDs that are sorted composites of the players' names (or IDs). For example:

```
playerInfo %>% 
  mutate(
    group_id = purrr::pmap_chr(
      .l = list(p1 = player1, p2 = player2, p3 = player3),
      .f = function(p1, p2, p3) paste(sort(c(p1, p2, p3)), collapse = "_")
    )
  ) %>% 
  group_by(group_id) %>% 
  summarise(
    lineup_ct = n(),
    total_pts = sum(points)
  )

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  group_id    lineup_ct total_pts
  <chr>           <int>     <dbl>
1 Bil_Joe_Nik         1         6
2 Bil_Joe_Tom         1         8
3 Joe_Nik_Tom         4        53
```

Comment: I'm honored that you created a stackoverflow account just to help with me - this approach seems great, will give it a try!